# как мне написать sql запрос, где нужно выбрать количество вопросов из таблицы билеты

Tags: mysql, sql

у меня есть таблица tickets и таблица questions в таблице questions есть поле id_ticket, мне нужно вытащить все билеты и количество вопросов в билете

```
SELECT *, COUNT(tickets.id) FROM `tickets`
LEFT JOIN `questions` ON (questions.id_ticket = tickets.id)
```

я пробовал что-то такого но оно не работает

Comment: Замените звезду на список конкретных полей.

Comment: Мне нужны все поля из таблицы tickets + поле question-count

Comment: Вам надо добавить group by и перечислить в нем все поля первой таблицы (по которой группировка собственно). И в данном случае `*` не поможет

Comment: @Mike спасибо помогло)